# ¿Por que me devuelve undefined? quiero conseguir sacarlo de ese array o cambiarlo TypesScript - Angular

Tags: html, c#, angular, typescript

Buenas soy algo nuevo en angular y el typescript y el problema que tengo que a la hora de imprimir los datos me salen como undefined apesar que en la consola me sale los datos que me los trae del servicio
Este es el metodo para obtener datos

```
    this.loading = true;
    this._mascotaService.getMascota(cedula_Profe).subscribe(data  => {   
      const resultado = [data];
      let profelist = resultado.map(element => { //esto de aqui era una prueba si lo podia sacar
        return element
      })    
      console.log(profelist);
      console.log(resultado[0].cedula_Profe)
      this.forma.patchValue({ 
        cedula_Profe : data.cedula_Profe,
        nombres_Profe: data.nombres_Profe,
        apellidos_Profe: data.apellidos_Profe,
        sexo_Profe: data.sexo_Profe,
        edad_Profe: data.edad_Profe,
        fecha_Nac_Profe: data.fecha_Nac_Profe,
        telefono_Profe: data.telefono_Profe,
        titulo_Academico: data.titulo_Academico,
        nombre_Titulo_Aca: data.nombre_Titulo_Aca,   
      })
      alert(data.cedula_Profe);
      debugger;
      this.loading = false;
    })
  }
```

como verán en la imagen aqui me devuelve los datos pero en el otro si quiero llamar a la cedula me sale como undefined
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

asi sale si en vez de profelist uso el data
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la interfaz

```
   export interface Mascota {
    
    cedula_Profe:String,
    nombres_Profe:string,
    apellidos_Profe:string,
    sexo_Profe:string,
    edad_Profe:string,
    fecha_Nac_Profe:string,
    telefono_Profe:string,
    titulo_Academico:string,
    nombre_Titulo_Aca:string,
    idDetalleProfesor:number,
}
```

Aqui es el html donde busco ingresar los datos en los input

```
<div class="container">
  <mat-card class="card">
      <mat-card-subtitle>
          Datos del Docente  {{ operacion }}    
      </mat-card-subtitle>
      <form [formGroup]="forma" (ngSubmit)="agregarEditarMascota()">
     
          <mat-grid-list  cols="3" rowHeight="80px">
              <mat-grid-tile [colspan]="1">
                  <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
                      <mat-label>Cedula</mat-label>
                      <input formControlName="cedula_Profe"   matInput autocomplete="off">
                  </mat-form-field>
              </mat-grid-tile>
              <mat-grid-tile>
                  <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
                      <mat-label>Nombre Completo</mat-label>
                      <input formControlName="nombres_Profe" matInput autocomplete="off">
                  </mat-form-field>
              </mat-grid-tile>
              <mat-grid-tile>
                  <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
                      <mat-label>Apellidos</mat-label>
                      <input formControlName="apellidos_Profe" matInput autocomplete="off">
                  </mat-form-field>
              </mat-grid-tile>
              <mat-grid-tile>
                  <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
                      <mat-label>Sexo</mat-label>
                      
                      <mat-select formControlName="sexo_Profe">
                        <mat-option value="Masculino">Masculino</mat-option>
                        <mat-option value="Femenino">Femenino</mat-option>
                      </mat-select>
                  </mat-form-field>
              </mat-grid-tile>
              <mat-grid-tile>
                  <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
                      <mat-label>Edad</mat-label>
                      <input type="number" formControlName="edad_Profe" matInput autocomplete="off">
                  </mat-form-field>
              </mat-grid-tile>
              <mat-grid-tile>
                <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
                    <mat-label>Fecha de Nacimiento</mat-label>
                    <input type="date" formControlName="fecha_Nac_Profe" matInput autocomplete="off">
                </mat-form-field>
            </mat-grid-tile>
            <mat-grid-tile>
              <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
                  <mat-label>Telefono</mat-label>
                  <input  formControlName="telefono_Profe" matInput autocomplete="off">
              </mat-form-field>
          </mat-grid-tile>
          <mat-grid-tile>
            <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
                <mat-label>Titulo Academico</mat-label>
                <input  formControlName="titulo_Academico" matInput autocomplete="off">
            </mat-form-field>
        </mat-grid-tile>
        <mat-grid-tile>
          <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
              <mat-label>Nombre del Titulo</mat-label>
              <input  formControlName="nombre_Titulo_Aca" matInput autocomplete="off">
          </mat-form-field>
      </mat-grid-tile>
              <mat-grid-tile [colspan]="3">
                  <button [disabled]="forma.invalid" type="submit" class="btnAceptar" mat-raised-button color="primary">Aceptar</button>
                  <button mat-raised-button routerLink="/profesor">Volver</button>
              </mat-grid-tile>
          </mat-grid-list>
      </form>
  </mat-card>
</div>
```

Y el servicio si lo quieren ver

```
getDetalle_Profesor(): Observable<Mascota[]> {
   return this.http.get<Mascota[]>(`${environment.apiUrl}/${this.url}`);
  }
  getMascota(cedula_Profes: string): Observable<Mascota> {
    return this.http.get<Mascota>(`${environment.apiUrl}/${this.url}/${cedula_Profes}`);
  }
```

seria de mucha ayuda si me pueden ayudar ante todo muchas gracias

Comment: Borra todo los que está dentro del subscribe y coloca `console.log(data)` y muestra que es lo que imprime

Comment: seria mejor si publicas el error tal como te sale y asi podriamos ver en que parte te da el undefined, se me ocurre que prodria ser que el formulario no esta inicializado, pero no puedo estar seguro porque no tengo el contexto del error.

Comment: ya lo corregi xd era una tonteria lo que pasa es que queria acceder a un array sin ser array asi que lo que hice fue esto const arrayProfe = Object.values(data); y ya con eso pude acceder a los datos